# Typescript assignment chaining

Tags: javascript, typescript, variable-assignment

```js
let a: {
    m?: string
};

let b = a = {};

b.m = ''; // Property 'm' does not exist on type '{}'.


let a: {
    m?: string
} = {};

let b = a;

b.m = ''; // It's OK
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBDeAoCKIFsD8cDOYBOAlgHYDmiAvgNyKKiQBGEAvNMwlTfQHRpsDkfSkA)

What happend when use assignment chaining? How to resolve this type error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with the first case:

```
let a: {
  m?: string
};

let b = a = {};
```

The type of `b` is inferred not from `a`, but from `{}`, this is why you can't access `m` from `b`.

In the second case

```
let a: {
    m?: string
} = {};

let b = a;
```

The type of `b` is inferred from `a`, that have the `m` property.

Why this?

Take the following example

```
let x = y = z;
```

`y = z` results in `z`, that's because the assignment is actually an expression.

So typescript check the type of `z` (in our case `{}`) and assign it to `x` (in our case `b`)

In order to fix the first case, you have to declare both `a` and `b` to `{ m?: string }`.

```
type Foo = {
    m?: string;
}

let a: Foo;

let b: Foo = a = {}
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUC2B+ALigGdgAnASwDsBzAbnQF910AbCYKAQyPjgbYcoAI14Jk3CambphAOhxQA9EqhwA1kA)

Answer (score 1):

With assignment chaining, the `b` variable gets the value of `{}` but does not get the type of `a`.

You need to create the `type` separately and apply it to `b` variable.

```
type A = {
    m?: string;
}

let a: A

let b: A = a = {};


b.m = '';
```

[PLAYGROUND LINK](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oFsD8AuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcKAviigDYTBQCG+MjLbARlwQchSOrUZ8AdJiEByWdSA)

Answer (score 1):

Chaining the assignment operator is possible in order to assign a single value to multiple variables ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment)).
So, assignment `let b = a = {};` is the same as the sequence of commands `let b = {}; a = {}`, in this case, you can see that `a` never assigns to `b`,
You can use the code below to get the expected result:

```
    let a: {
      m?: string
    };
    let b = a;
    b = a = {};
```